# Display content from various sources

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

What is the best way to display content from multiple sources(websites)? For example, Display news from various news sites to your site. Not links but actual content. I want to automate this process and avoid any manual intervention.

For Now I have a macro in excel which gets data from these websites and then I insert it into SQL server.

So currently: Excel --> SQL Server --> dbViews --> HTML

I want to get rid of the Excel step and automate it if possible.

Is there any way I can write a model class to handle this data? Get/manipulate data and display it on my page without inserting it in SQL Server DB?

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Send HTTP requests (`HttpClient`) and parse HTML (HTML Agility Pack)

Comment: It is called Web Scraping. There is a lot to it.

Comment: Be aware that the content on other peoples' sites may be copyrighted. Linking to it is typically permissible. Taking it and displaying it inline on your own site might not be.